# iOS 8 Framework written in Swift

Tags: swift, frameworks, ios8

How do you create an iOS 8 Dynamic Framework using Swift?  I have added the target, selected Swift as my language etc... But in the MyKit framework it wants me to add the MyKit/publicheaders.h #imports.  Swift files don't have a concept of .h and .m and when I try #import MyKit/myAPI.swift the complier can't find it.

What am I doing wrong?  I've found examples that use objective-c for the source code in the framework, but none using swift.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at apple [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), it explains how to mix Objective C and Swift.